# Converting the following xpath //div[@id='sb-search']/form/span[2] to css selector

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to convert the following xpath `//div[@id='sb-search']/form/span[2]` to a css selector in order to use it in Selenium.

I have tried the following but no luck in Internet Explorer 11:

```
search_icon = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#sb-search > form > span:nth-child(2)')
```

Comment: it works in Firefox but not IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `:nth-of-type(2)`, not `:nth-child(2)`, since `span[2]` finds the second `span`, not the second child when it is a `span`:

```
search_icon = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#sb-search > form > span:nth-of-type(2)')
```